# How to set variable value from column data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to declare a variable for reusability for this query:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(Email, CHARINDEX('@', Email) + 1, LEN(Email) - CHARINDEX('@', Email)), 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    Student
GROUP BY 
    SUBSTRING(Email, CHARINDEX('@', Email) + 1, LEN(Email) - CHARINDEX('@', Email))
```

The variable holds `SUBSTRING(Email,CHARINDEX('@', Email)+1,LEN(Email)-CHARINDEX('@', Email))`

But it seems that the column data is not reachable outside `SELECT` statement:

```
DECLARE @exp NVARCHAR(20) =    
   SUBSTRING(Email,CHARINDEX('@', Email)+1,LEN(Email)-CHARINDEX('@', Email))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method of doing this uses a view; another uses a CTE.  I happen like using `OUTER APPLY` because it makes it easy to add lots of variables that refer to each other:

```
SELECT domain, COUNT(*)
FROM Student s OUTER APPLY
     (VALUES ( SUBSTRING(s.Email, CHARINDEX('@', s.Email) + 1, LEN(s.Email) - CHARINDEX('@', s.Email)) )
     ) v(domain)
GROUP BY domain;
```

Or, you could write:

```
SELECT domain, COUNT(*)
FROM Student s OUTER APPLY
     (VALUES ( CHARINDEX('@', s.Email) )
     ) as pos(pos)
     (VALUES ( SUBSTRING(s.Email, pos.po + 1, LEN(s.Email) - pos.pos) )
     ) v(domain)
GROUP BY domain;
```

And, finally, you might find this expression easier:

```
SELECT domain, COUNT(*)
FROM Student s OUTER APPLY
     (VALUES ( STUFF(s.Email, 1, CHARINDEX('@', s.Email), '') )
     ) v(domain)
GROUP BY domain;
```

With this simplification, you might not even want an additional variable at all.

Comment: What is `v`and why is it arbitrary character?

Comment: @MohamedAhmed A _derived table_ used in a `FROM` clause requires an _alias_. [Ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx). It could just as well be named `Zelmo`.